# Understanding the actual wattage of LED (LM301H)

Tags: led, watts

LED under consideration is LM301H from samsung:

Product page link - https://www.samsung.com/led/lighting/mid-power-leds/3030-leds/lm301h/

Datasheet link - https://cdn.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2020/03/Data_Sheet_LM301H_CRI80_Rev.5.1.pdf

The product page mentions the wattage as 0.2 W.

However, in the datasheet, max current is mentioned as 200 mA and Vf is around 2.7 V. Product of these values gives 0.54 W. On a side note, there are products available that use this LED and run it at 0.47 W.

What value of wattage should I consider for this LED?

Comment: Where do you see 200mA - in the "Absolute Maximum Rating" table? Absolute Max ratings are not normal operating conditions. You'll see pretty much everywhere else in the datasheet that specs are given with a 65mA operating current.

Comment: @brhans - 65 mA is mentioned as sorting current. I feel that's the current value they used for binning the LED chips. Second, the availability of successful/popular products that run individual LEDs at roughly 0.5 W makes me believe so. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sheet talks about lifetime checks using 200 mA and at an elevated temperature of 85°C. The figure tested is for 1000 hours and that's only 42 days: -

[image]

Now I'm not saying it won't last longer than that because it surely will but, I'd want to know properly how to derate current in order to get lifetime extensions massively in excess of those figures quoted. I'd be talking with Samsung about this.

Answer (score 2):

200mA is absolute maximum current, which is just what it sounds like (steady state; pulsed current is higher).  All their testing data is 65mA, which looks like their "recommended" operating current, although they don't have a separate table for recommended operating conditions.  CRI data, binning, etc is also done at 65mA so they're saying that if you want the specs off the datasheet, run them at that current.

Comment: So I can design with 200 mA as the max current. Right? (I will consider derating it for sure, maybe around 150-160 mA will pass through each LED)

Comment: If you mean that you are designing so that the current through the LED never exceeds 200mA, then yes.  That means looking at your component tolerances all the way back to the power supply.  540mW dissipation isn't huge but if you're packing these close together then you might run into problems.  There's a handy brief on laying out the 3030 package here: https://www.lumileds.com/wp-content/uploads/files/AB207-luxeon-3030-line-application-brief.pdf

Comment: @Whiskeyjack You may also need to derate the current if your ambient temperature is high, as described in the datasheet. Make sure that your mounting method provides sufficient heatsinking to keep the die temperature below maximum.

Answer (score 1):

> On a side note, there are products available that use this LED and run it at 0.47 W.

The absolute max is given as a current, but you're talking about power.  Power depends on voltage, and the datasheet is clear that not all parts have the same voltage:

[image]

That range gives power dissipation between 0.52W for the best parts to 0.58W for the worst parts.  A product running very close to the absolute max is probably cheaply made, so likely to be using the cheapest parts (and possibly even worse ones then in your datasheet), so still below max, possibly well below depending on the bin.

> What value of wattage should I consider for this LED?

Why do you ask?  Wattage is a value you choose, so asking what you should consider it to be doesn't make sense.  Generally the wattage is not of direct interest for an LED since it is only indirectly related to things you care about such as light output and thermal dissipation.  Instead you care about the total luminous flux, the drive current, the luminous efficiency, the thermal dissipation, and the worst case forward voltage, none of which are directly determined by the input power.

Comment: Indeed, the lower Vf bins have higher efficiency (are "better"). As all bins are rated for the exact same current, the "better" leds effectively must be operated at lower power (wattage) than "bad" ones with a higher Vf to comply with the absolute maximum rating. So it really doesn't make much sense to use power to make a design decision.

Comment: I agree with you guys. I am not going to design with a focus on dissipating so much power in the LED. I asked this question to understand how much current I can push through each LED. And at that current whether I will be in safe wattage zone or not. Since mentioned wattage on the product page is 0.2 W as compared to calculated max wattage that comes around 0.52 W for top bin LEDs, I wanted to be sure whether my max wattage limit should be 0.2 W or somewhere around 0.5 W for my design check.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Efficiency of LEDs is higher at lower currents and then drops off at higher current. The typical current usually represents a point around which the efficiency is still high but close to where it begins to be more severely degraded. Since you are buying the highest efficiency white LEDs available, presumably efficiency is import to your application. You can find test data for the lm301b online, and from there should be straightforward to pick an operating point that works for your application.

Comment: @user1850479 - can you please give me a link for lm301b test reports. I am unable to find it.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack  Here is one vendor's testing:  https://horticulturelightinggroup.com/pages/qb120-board-guide-1